# How to display RBAC user role in Kartik's GridView - Yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2, roles, rbac, kartik-v

I have a "users" table in my DB and I display the content of this table in Kartik's GridView like this:

```
<?php
 $gridColumns = [
   [
     'class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn',
     'width' => '20px',
   ],
   'email',
   'name',
   'surname',
   [
     'class' => 'kartik\grid\BooleanColumn',
     'label' => 'Disabled?',
     'attribute' => 'isDisabled',
     'trueLabel' => 'Yes',
     'falseLabel' => 'No'
   ],
   [
     'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
     'width' => '100px',
   ],
 ];
 echo GridView::widget([
   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   'filterModel' => $searchModel,
   'columns' => $gridColumns,
   'pjax' => true,
   'bordered' => true,
   'striped' => false,
   'condensed' => false,
   'responsive' => true,
   'hover' => true,
   'panel' => [
     'type' => GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,
     'heading' => "<h3 class=\"panel-title\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-user\"></i>$this->title </h3>",
     'after' => false,
     'before' => false
   ],
 ]);
?>
```

I also use RBAC and I have 2 roles (admin and manager).

**What I need to do**
I need to put in the above GridView the role of each user and also have the possibility to filter the data by that role.
Preferably the class of that "Role" column should be 'kartik\grid\EnumColumn' because I have just 2 roles.

 I don't know where to start, any hint could be good.

Comment: Why are you iterating over the roles but reassigning them on every iteration? Since you only have two roles, you could also do `return Yii::$app->user->can('admin') ? 'admin' : 'manager';` Assuming that the roles are independent, or manager is a child of admin, that would work.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I hadn't thought about it!

Comment: @RaulSauco your code would always return the role of user that is currently logged in, but he need the role of user at current row in grid instead.

Comment: @MichalHynčica good point, I didn't notice that. Then `Yii::$app->authManager->getRolesByUser(...)` would be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

I finally found a working solution, here is the code of the GridView:

```
           <?php
                $gridColumns = [
                    [
                        'class' => 'kartik\grid\SerialColumn',
                        'width' => '20px',
                    ],
                    'email',
                    'name',
                    'surname',
                    [
                        'class' => 'kartik\grid\EnumColumn',
                        'enum' => ['admin', 'manager'],
                        'filter' => [
                            'admin' => 'admin',
                            'manager' => 'manager',
                        ],
                        'label' => 'Role',
                        'attribute' => 'authAssignment',
                        'value' => 'authAssignment.item_name'
                    ],
                    [
                        'class' => 'kartik\grid\BooleanColumn',
                        'label' => 'Disabled?',
                        'attribute' => 'isDisabled',
                        'trueLabel' => 'Yes',
                        'falseLabel' => 'No'
                    ],
                    [
                        'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
                        'width' => '100px',
                    ],
                ];
                echo GridView::widget([
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
                    'columns' => $gridColumns,
                    'pjax' => true,
                    'bordered' => true,
                    'striped' => false,
                    'condensed' => false,
                    'responsive' => true,
                    'hover' => true,
                    'panel' => [
                        'type' => GridView::TYPE_PRIMARY,
                        'heading' => "<h3 class=\"panel-title\"><i class=\"glyphicon glyphicon-user\"></i> $this->title </h3>",
                        'after' => false,
                        'before' => false
                    ],
                ]);
            ?>
```

I added this relation to my User model to retrieve the roles of the users:

```
public function getAuthAssignment(){
    return $this->hasOne(AuthAssignment::className(), ['user_id'=>'id']);
}
```

In the UserSearch model I added this property and this rule:

```
public $authAssignment;
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ...
        [['authAssignment'], 'safe'],
    ];
}
```

And finally I changed like this my search function in the UserSearch model:

```
public function search($params)
{
    $query = User::find();
    $query->leftJoin('public.auth_assignment', 'id=user_id::integer');
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);

    $dataProvider->sort->attributes['authAssignment'] = [
        'asc' => ['auth_assignment.item_name' => SORT_ASC],
        'desc' => ['auth_assignment.item_name' => SORT_DESC],
    ];

    if (!($this->load($params) && $this->validate())) {
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'isDisabled' => $this->isDisabled,
        'auth_assignment.item_name' => $this->authAssignment,
    ]);

    $query->andFilterWhere(['ilike', 'email', $this->email])
        ->andFilterWhere(['ilike', 'name', $this->name])
        ->andFilterWhere(['ilike', 'surname', $this->surname]);

    return $dataProvider;
}
```